# AFNetworking: How to make AFHTTPClient handle both json and xml responses?

Tags: ios, xml, json, afnetworking

can one AFTHTTPClient handle both json and xml?

I have one single domain in which some services only return json, while others only return xml.  How would I make a GET request and instruct AFHTTPClient to use AFJSONRequestOperation for some services and an AFXMLRequestOperation for other GET requests?

So what I would like is:

```
chairs.com  GET customerprofile  ---> returns XML (no option for json)

charis.com GET inventory ---> returns JSON (no option for xml)
```

Is this a job for multiple AFHTTPClients? 
Thanks

Comment: Isn't the parsing of the response is a function of the type of operation you instantiate, not the `AFHTTPClient`? The only thing that seems potentially problematic is if (a) the two types of requests required a different `AFHTTPClientParameterEncoding`; and (b) if you were doing this from separate threads and ended up with some race condition, but, even then, with proper synchronization, you should be fine. Is there some reason you concluded that this wouldn't work?

Comment: @Rob You are correct; I presume the OP wants to use the convenience `getPath:…` methods, instead of building an operation each time.

Answer (score 7):

Your use of `AFHTTPClient` indicates you're using AFNetworking 1, but I'll answer this question for both versions, for future readers.

#### AFNetworking 1.x

You just need to register the appropriate AFHTTPOperation subclass.  This is typically done in your subclass of `initWithBaseURL:`:

```
- (instancetype) initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];

    if (self) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFXMLRequestOperation class]];
    }
    
    return self;
}
```

When your app makes an outgoing request, you'll need to make sure your `accept` headers are set appropriately (for example, to `text/json` or `text/xml`, depending on what you expect from which endpoint you hit).  Otherwise, AFNetworking won't know which operation to use for which request.

There are a few ways to easily solve this `Accept` header requirement.  If one of your endpoints is an exception to a general rule, I might do this by overriding `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:`:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                      path:(NSString *)path
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters {

    request = [super requestWithMethod:method path:path parameters:parameters];

    if (/* the endpoint specified in path returns XML */) {
        [request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    } else {
        [request setValue:@"text/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    }

}
```

This is a small violation of [tell, don't ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask); feel free to refactor as necessary.

If you don't plan on upgrading to AFNetworking 2, then you can stop reading here.

#### AFNetworking 2.x

Version 2.0 of AFNetworking makes this simpler and more intuitive.  In 2.0, the serialization responsibility is broken out into a separate class. Instances of this class are called *response serializers*. When you upgrade, you'll want an AFCompoundResponseSerializer.  The documentation describes it best:

> `AFCompoundSerializer` is a subclass of `AFHTTPSerializer` that delegates the response serialization to the first `AFHTTPSerializer` object that returns `YES` to `validateResponse:data:error:`, falling back on the default behavior of `AFHTTPSerializer`. This is useful for supporting multiple potential types and structures of server responses with a single serializer.

For example:

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *jsonSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:0];
AFXMLDocumentSerializer *xmlSerializer = [AFXMLDocumentSerializer serializerWithXMLDocumentOptions:0];

AFCompoundResponseSerializer *compoundSerializer = [AFCompoundResponseSerializer compoundSerializerWithResponseSerializers:@[jsonSerializer, xmlSerializer]];

[AFHTTPSessionManager manager].responseSerializer = compoundSerializer;
```

Comment: I tried this but I didn't see the acceptableContentTypes set get updated, it's still nil after I created the  compound serializer

http://pastebin.com/DJgsayag 
^^ This is what I am trying to do, but to no success apparently.

Comment: @MichaelNguyen You should open a new question for this, but it looks like you're adding `text/html` to  `acceptableContentTypes` only the compound serializer. You also need to set it on the individual serializer that you want to actually handle `text/html`. (See [the implementation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/0f3829f6afdfa57eced1e80c317e68ca5e5f85d0/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.m#L746).)

Comment: for the purposes of the project, just getting it to accept the content is good enough.  I understand your point though.  I figured out the problem.  I needed to add the serializers to the requestOperation object I created.  I was hoping that setting it on the manager level, it would flow down into subsequent calls.  guess not. :)  thanks.

Comment: Looking in impl for AFURLResponseSerialization, there doesn't seem to be a default serializer for text/html.  I suppose that means I'd have to write my own.  Am I right in this or am I missing something here?

Comment: @MichaelNguyen You should open a new question for this.

Comment: In AFNetworking 2.5 Xcode can't see `AFXMLDocumentSerializer` class.

Comment: @surfrider Try `AFXMLDocumentResponseSerializer` in newer versions of AFNetworking.

Comment: @aaronbrager doesn't work too: AFXMLDocumentResponseSerializer placed in some #define macro and xcode can't see it.

Comment: @surfrider You should post a new question describing your specific circumstances

Comment: @aaronbrager Okay, thanks, for now i solved this problem in another way, but i will follow your recommendations if i get back to this case.